# Exponent operator performance

Tags: haskell

Okay maybe a silly question here, but I am currently learning haskell by completing problems on projecteuler.net

I ran into an interesting observation and was hoping someone could shed some light why things are the way they are.

For reference, I was implementing [Problem #29](http://projecteuler.net/problem=29)
Here's what I came up

```
nub $ [ a^^b | a <- [2..100], b <- [2..100] ]
```

I observed that using the `^^` operator is faster than `**` which is faster than `^` for the input listed above.

My question is simply, why?  Each of these operators applies to different type classes.  My guess is there is some type conversions taking place, but I would expect `^` to be the faster of the operations, when it seems it's actually the oposite.

Thanks!

Comment: If the list isn't very short (which it isn't), don't use nub. It is O(n^2).

Comment: There are no type conversions in Haskell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the time is spent on `nub`. With `^^` and `**` you're doing `nub` on `[Double]`. With `^` it is `nub` on `[Integer]`, and comparing big integers is slower than comparing doubles.

Comment: Right, `nub` is doing all the work in the example.  Thanks for making that clear.

Answer (score 4):

`**` and `^^` are using `Double`, but `^` is using `Integer`. You really can’t compare a floating point operation to a big integer function. Take a look at the [implementation of `^`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Real.html#%5E).

In your code, the following are true:

- `**` is implemented in hardware.
- `^` uses big `Integer` in a tail-recursive loop.
- `^^` is the same, except with `Double`.

So your observations about their relative performance make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The thing I've found while working through Project Euler problems is that types can make a huge difference in runtime performance.  For example:

```
foo :: Integral a => a -> a
foo' :: Integer -> Integer
foo'' :: Int -> Int
```

all have very different performance.  Imagine my surprise when I discovered that simply letting the compiler infer the most generic type for `foo`, rather than specifying it myself, was causing poor performance.

Performance is also (obviously) highly dependent on your environment: are you running compiled or interpreted? Optimized or un-optimized?  The point is that in some circumstances you might have unboxed, primitive `Int#`s under the covers rather than boxed, heap-allocated values...  Unfortunately I'm still enough of a n00b myself that I don't know when you'll get one vs. the other :(

So, maybe this is a dumb answer, but if you're using GHC and you're familiar with C programming, try using the `-keep-hc-files` flag to compare the intermediate C code generated when you use `^` vs. `^^` vs. `**`.

Comment: You'll get Int# when the compiler sees the Ints are strictly needed. You can help with bang patterns, but do check the core whether you got them, and measure whether it really helps. On another note, .hc files are only generated by unregisterised compilers (says the user's guide), so most won't have them anyway.